# Facing issue making my Next JS project PWA

Tags: reactjs, next.js, progressive-web-apps

I am new to programming and working on a Next Js project, I want to make it PWA but on running npm run build, sw.js and workbox.js both are not generating.

**next.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/",
        destination: "/dashboard",
        permanent: false,
      },
    ];
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;

const withPWA = require("next-pwa");

module.exports = withPWA({
  dest: "public",
  register: true,
  skipWaiting: true,
  disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
  swDest: "service-worker.js", // Specify the service worker file name
  generateInDevMode: false,
});

// Injected content via Sentry wizard below

const { withSentryConfig } = require("@sentry/nextjs");

module.exports = withSentryConfig(
  module.exports,
  {
    // For all available options, see:
    // https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-webpack-plugin#options

    // Suppresses source map uploading logs during build
    silent: true,

    org: "antiquelogic-kf",
    project: "javascript-nextjs",
  },
  {
    // For all available options, see:
    // https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/nextjs/manual-setup/

    // Upload a larger set of source maps for prettier stack traces (increases build time)
    widenClientFileUpload: true,

    // Transpiles SDK to be compatible with IE11 (increases bundle size)
    transpileClientSDK: true,

    // Routes browser requests to Sentry through a Next.js rewrite to circumvent ad-blockers (increases server load)
    tunnelRoute: "/monitoring",

    // Hides source maps from generated client bundles
    hideSourceMaps: true,

    // Automatically tree-shake Sentry logger statements to reduce bundle size
    disableLogger: true,
  }
);

// Custom server configuration
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/",
        destination: "/home",
        permanent: false,
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

**/public/manifest.json**

```
{
    "theme_color": "#003466",
    "background_color": "#FFF",
    "display": "browser",
    "scope": "/",
    "start_url": "/home",
    "name": "AntiqueLogic",
    "short_name": "AL",
    "description": "AntiqueLogic is dedicated to providing high-quality IT solutions that help businesses succeed. Our team of experts is committed to using agile methodologies to deliver top-notch work that meets your needs and exceeds your expectations.",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "./maskable.png",
            "sizes": "48x48",
            "type": "image/x-icon",
            "purpose": "maskable"
        },
        {
            "src": "./icon-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "./icon-256x256.png",
            "sizes": "256x256",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "./icon-384x384.png",
            "sizes": "384x384",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "./icon-512x512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ]
}
```

**/pages/_document.js**

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"
        />
        <meta
          name="description"
          content="AntiqueLogic is dedicated to providing high-quality IT solutions that help businesses succeed. Our team of experts is committed to using agile methodologies to deliver top-notch work that meets your needs and exceeds your expectations."
        />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#003466" />
        <title>AntiqueLogic</title>
        <link rel="manifest" href="../public/manifest.json" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../public/favicon.ico" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="../public/apple-icon.png"></link>
      </Head>
    );
  }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

**package.json**

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "^2.0.19",
    "@chakra-ui/next-js": "^2.1.4",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.7.1",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@react-spring/parallax": "^9.7.3",
    "@sentry/nextjs": "^7.56.0",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "country-codes-list": "^1.6.11",
    "eslint": "8.43.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.7",
    "framer-motion": "^10.12.16",
    "lottie-react": "^2.4.0",
    "next": "13.4.7",
    "next-pwa": "^5.6.0",
    "postcss": "8.4.24",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-countup": "^6.4.2",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-intersection-observer": "^9.5.1",
    "react-select": "^5.7.3",
    "react-spring": "^9.7.2",
    "react-use-gesture": "^9.1.3",
    "sharp": "^0.32.1",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2"
  }
```

[image: My folder structure]

I have tried doing everything, changed my next.config.js file in every way but nothing is seem to be working. I want my project to be PWA.